# Can I keep Windows 10 computer certificate on a different partition and prevent installation?

Tags: certificate, windows

I would like to reimage a machine while keeping the computer certificate on a different drive, causing the re-imaged computer use an existing certificate on a drive partition that wasn't overwritten, preventing the need to re-install it once again from PFX. My intention is to install the certificate once on a path other than drive C: (let's say on a Drive D:) and prevent the key from being exported.

1. Make sure Windows can use the certificate from a different path with no installation after computer re-image because the private key will not be exportable?
2. Deploy/keep operating system certificate to a different path not C: preferably D: that will be kept during computer reimage?

Comment: What do you mean by "computer certificate" _(this could apply to multiple things)_?

Comment: The certificate store is always stored on the system partition so there's no way around that. You'd need to restore the keys from the original pkcs12 file (.p12/.pfx) that you used to import the public/private key pair after reinstalling the computer.

Comment: what about creating a different certificate store on another drive? is it possible?

Comment: Why? What are you doing for actual trying to accomplish?

Comment: I would like to keep the certificate (private key) for the computer on a different drive partition.
so if in a scenario where I will re-image the machine operating system partition, for example, drive C: the machine certificates located on a different drive on a different certificate store will still exist, and I would not need to reinstall it from a file (PFX) which is exportable.

I have found this link, but I'm looking for instructions:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/managing-certificates-with-certificate-stores